# Jquery Scroll Event - Fixed Element Middle Page

Tags: jquery

I have table in the middle of a page with a fixed THEAD element. Users can then scroll down the TR elements and the THEAD remains fixed at the top showing specifics of the table.

Is there a way to attach a scroll to a fixed Table THEAD and then highlight the top most TR as a user scrolls past them?

thanks

Comment: can you share your HTML code plz?

Comment: So you want to have table with THEAD fixed and TBODY scroll?

Comment: Are you implying you have multiple tables that you would like to use a shared Fixed Head with?